# polynomial associates if constant multiples

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have polynomials $2x^2+3x+1$ and $3x^2+2x+4$. I need to figure out if they are associates in $\mathbb{Q[x]}$ and $\mathbb{Z_5[x]}$.

I know that two polynomials are associates iff they are constant multiples of each other.

For the rationals i believe the answer is no. and for $Z_5$ I am not certain.

Comment: you just need to check if the equations $2n \equiv_5 3, 3n \equiv_5 2$ and $1n \equiv_5 4$ have a common solution